# array replace value only specific keys

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have two array that in json something like this  (label)  :

```
[
    {
      "dates": "2019-07-01",
      "c_job": 0
    },
    {
      "dates": "2019-07-02",
      "c_job": 0
    },
    {
      "dates": "2019-07-03",
      "c_job": 0
    },
    {
      "dates": "2019-07-04",
      "c_job": 0
    }
  ]
```

and the others data from database something like this (data)  :

```
{
    "EXPORT": [
      {
        "dates": "2019-07-01",
        "c_job": 12
      },
      {
        "dates": "2019-07-02",
        "c_job": 8
      },
      {
        "dates": "2019-07-04",
        "c_job": 11
      }
    ],
    "IMPORT": [
      {
        "dates": "2019-07-03",
        "c_job": 11
      }
    ]
}
```

after that i try array replace to make data precision with label with this code :

```
foreach($data as $key => $value) {
            $datafinal[$key] = array_replace($label,$value);
        }
```

and the output is (datafinal)  :

```
{
    "EXPORT": [
      {
        "dates": "2019-07-01",
        "c_job": 12
      },
      {
        "dates": "2019-07-02",
        "c_job": 8
      },
      {
        "dates": "2019-07-04",
        "c_job": 11
      },
      {
        "dates": "2019-07-04",
        "c_job": 0
      }
    ],
    "IMPORT": [
      {
        "dates": "2019-07-03",
        "c_job": 11
      },
      {
        "dates": "2019-07-02",
        "c_job": 0
      },
      {
        "dates": "2019-07-03",
        "c_job": 0
      },
      {
        "dates": "2019-07-04",
        "c_job": 0
      }
    ]
  }
```

what i want is something like this :

```
{
    "EXPORT": [
      {
        "dates": "2019-07-01",
        "c_job": 12
      },
      {
        "dates": "2019-07-02",
        "c_job": 8
      },
      {
        "dates": "2019-07-03",
        "c_job": 0
      },
      {
        "dates": "2019-07-04",
        "c_job": 11
      }
    ],
    "IMPORT": [
      {
        "dates": "2019-07-01",
        "c_job": 0
      },
      {
        "dates": "2019-07-02",
        "c_job": 0
      },
      {
        "dates": "2019-07-03",
        "c_job": 11
      },
      {
        "dates": "2019-07-04",
        "c_job": 0
      }
    ]
  }
```

i have try array reduce and replace

Comment: _“[I] have [tried] array reduce and replace”_ — please [edit] your question and share your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what you need to do is for each top-level array in `$data`, go through the 0 value array (I've called it `$blank`) and see if the date exists in the current `$data` array. If it does, copy that value, otherwise use the blank value:

```
$datafinal = array();
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($blank as $bkey => $bvalue) {
        if (($dkey = array_search($bvalue['dates'], array_column($value, 'dates'))) !== false) {
            $datafinal[$key][$bkey] = $value[$dkey];
        }
        else {
            $datafinal[$key][$bkey] = $bvalue;
        }
    }
}
echo json_encode($datafinal, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Output:

```
{
    "EXPORT": [
        {
            "dates": "2019-07-01",
            "c_job": 12
        },
        {
            "dates": "2019-07-02",
            "c_job": 8
        },
        {
            "dates": "2019-07-03",
            "c_job": 0
        },
        {
            "dates": "2019-07-04",
            "c_job": 11
        }
    ],
    "IMPORT": [
        {
            "dates": "2019-07-01",
            "c_job": 0
        },
        {
            "dates": "2019-07-02",
            "c_job": 0
        },
        {
            "dates": "2019-07-03",
            "c_job": 11
        },
        {
            "dates": "2019-07-04",
            "c_job": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/j0u9h)

Answer (score 0):

I've gone for the old and simple nested `foreach` loops, about as simple and quick as you can get (comments in code)...

```
$template = json_decode('[
    {
      "dates": "2019-07-01",
      "c_job": 0
    },
    {
      "dates": "2019-07-02",
      "c_job": 0
    },
    {
      "dates": "2019-07-03",
      "c_job": 0
    },
    {
      "dates": "2019-07-04",
      "c_job": 0
    }
  ]', true);

$update = json_decode('{
    "EXPORT": [
      {
        "dates": "2019-07-01",
        "c_job": 12
      },
      {
        "dates": "2019-07-02",
        "c_job": 8
      },
      {
        "dates": "2019-07-04",
        "c_job": 11
      }
    ],
    "IMPORT": [
      {
        "dates": "2019-07-03",
        "c_job": 11
      }
    ]
}', true);
```

And the main code...

```
// Create blank output array with all entries
$output = ["EXPORT" => $template, "IMPORT" => $template];

// Loop over update data (from database) - you may need to tweak this for your use case
foreach ( $update  as $type => $updateItem )   {
    // Loop over each set of update values (a row of dates and c_job)
    foreach ( $updateItem  as $updateItem )   {
        // Locate in empty output array
        foreach ( $output[$type] as &$item )   {
            // Same date - update
            if ( $updateItem['dates'] == $item['dates']) {
                $item['c_job'] = $updateItem['c_job'];
                // Stop looking as already updated
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A shorter, but involves a lot more `array_` functions, this creates the template arrays with the date as the key, so then you can use the dates from the input data to directly update the data...

```
// Create template array using dates as the array key
$template = array_column($template, null, 'dates');
$output = ["EXPORT" => $template, "IMPORT" => $template];

foreach ( $update  as $type => $export )   {
    foreach ( $export  as $export )   {
        // Use the combination of type (EXPORT) and dates from the update data
        // to directly update the output (assumes empty value created)
        $output[$type][$export['dates']]['c_job'] = $export['c_job'];
    }
}

// Re-index data to remove dates as keys
$output = ["EXPORT" => array_values($output['EXPORT']), 
    "IMPORT" => array_values($output['IMPORT'])];
```